# opening file explorer view on jsp using javascript/jquery to save file in client side desired location

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

Need to open file explorer view(as we see usually see in open file dialog box) in a div or sth with a save button on it, on the click of which, will take decided url and save file by java call).The java thing will be taken care of but need to work on file explorer dialog box... want to use something supported by atleast half of the upper-end browsers.

Maybe way explained, it looks the same, but its not since user needs to give the desired location to save the file with desired name, that file explorer is needed to be done in js/html(with a save button to call servlet to fetch desired link. to save the file already in java class). Review again...

Comment: It's exactly the same.

Comment: what part you guys don't understand??!! I want the similar explorer view to be designed in **javascript/jquery**, **NOT** whole of this in **JAVA solely**. the solution links given in that question, are wholly done in java.... Please reconsider.....

Comment: I don't understand if you want your file dialog to save the file to the user's computer or save the file to the server. If you want it to save to the user's computer, then you cannot design it in Java, or in JavaScript, or in jQuery. In fact, you cannot design it at all. No-one can. The only thing you can do is display the dialog that's already built in to the web browser. Since the file is currently on the server, the only way to do that is to have a button or link that causes the server to start a download using `"Content-Disposition: attachment"`. So see the linked answer. Where am I wrong?

Comment: it's definitely possible in java. That's i'm sure of, since one can save the file now upto my knowledge by either somethings like awt(filechooser), or jfilechooser(swing)(dont want to use swing since there're not supported anymore). seen some deployed ones but couldn't make anything out of it..This is why I came here for some better answers....

Comment: Swing is still supported. But you said you're using JSP, so the Java here is **on the server**. If you use `java.awt.FileDialog` or `javax.swing.JFileChooser`, it will display a file save dialog **on the server** (if it even has a screen) where no-one will see it, not on the user's screen. But you said you didn't want to use Java. And yet, the file is on the server, which uses Java, so you cannot not use Java. You're not making any sense.

Comment: Now I'm not sure about swing being supported or not... but atleast my friend, I didn't say that I dont want to use java at all. I'm saying till now I prefer creating that file explorer UI part in js/jquery rest i have already done in java. If nothing is there, ofcourse java will be used. but I'm not sure how? java.awt.FileDialog or javax.swing.JFileChooser I need more details...

Comment: The Java here is **on the server**. If you use `java.awt.FileDialog` or `javax.swing.JFileChooser`, it will display a file save dialog **on the server** where no-one will see it, not on the user's screen. You need something that's **on the client**. It's impossible to implement such a dialog in JavaScript. (Why would anyone even want to?) The only thing you can do is display the dialog that's already built in to the web browser by sending the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header in the HTTP response. So see the linked answer.